# Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton

Tags: c#

public partial class Form2 : Form
{

```
 public bool male {get; set;}

{
 InitializeComponent();
} 
 private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        maleGender_rb1 = male;
    }

}
```

I want to display the radio buttton result from form1 to form2 using also radio buttons

Comment: Did you mean to use the `Checked` property of the radio button? e.g. this `maleGender_rb1.Checked = male;`

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to setup an event in the child form and for the RadioButton controls subscribe to CheckedChanged. The CheckedChange event determines which RadioButton was checked and sends notification to any listeners.

**Child form**:

namespace PassStringFromChildToParentForm
{
public partial class ChildForm : Form
{
public delegate void OnPassData(bool isMale);
public event OnPassData PassData;

```
    public ChildForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MaleRadioButton.Checked = true;
        MaleRadioButton.CheckedChanged += RadioButton_CheckedChanged;
        FemaleRadioButton.CheckedChanged += RadioButton_CheckedChanged;
    }

    private void RadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var radioButton = (RadioButton)sender;
        if (radioButton.Checked)
        {
            PassData?.Invoke(radioButton == MaleRadioButton);
        }
    }

    public void UpdateRadioButton(bool isMale)
    {
        if (isMale)
        {
            MaleRadioButton.Checked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            FemaleRadioButton.Checked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

}

**Main Form**:

Here we subscribe to the child form event and determine which RadioButton to check based on the bool value passed.

```
namespace PassStringFromChildToParentForm
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        private ChildForm _childForm;
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MaleRadioButton.CheckedChanged += RadioButton_CheckedChanged;
            FemaleRadioButton.CheckedChanged += RadioButton_CheckedChanged;
        }

        private void RadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Application.OpenForms.OfType<ChildForm>().Count() != 1) return;
            var radioButton = (RadioButton)sender;
            if (!radioButton.Checked) return;
            if (!radioButton.Checked) return;
            _childForm.UpdateRadioButton(MaleRadioButton.Checked);

        }

        private void ShowChildForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _childForm = new ChildForm();
            _childForm.PassData += ChildForm_PassData; ;
            _childForm.Show(this);
            
        }
        private void ChildForm_PassData(bool isMale)
        {
            if (isMale)
            {
                MaleRadioButton.Checked = true;
            }
            else
            {
                FemaleRadioButton.Checked = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked, however, when I either selected Male or Female radiobutton in the Main Form, in the Child Form the Male radiobutton is always checked.

Comment: See revised code

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert `bool` to `RadioButton`. I think you need to use `Checked` property of radio button to pass boolean value to it.

For example:

```
maleGender_rb1.Checked = true;// or false
```

Comment: sometimes a more afirmative answer makes whoever asks more confident on the answer. Instead "_I think you need to use Checked property_" you could say "_you should use the `Checked` property_". Also, the code snippet could be `maleGender_rb1.Checked = male;` because OP already has a boolean property for that radio button.